# How to extract values of individual objects from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this

```
const jsonx =[{"name":"John Doe"},{"name2":"Marry Doe"},{"name3":"Michael"}]
```

What I am trying to achieve are the values of each object out of the array as follows

```
{"name":"John Doe","name2":"Marry Doe","name3":"Michael"}
```

I have tried the following methods, but did not manage to get what I need.

```
//console.log(Array.of(...jsonx));
//console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonx));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can make use of ES6's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). (My favourite way of doing things)

```js
const jsonx =[{"name":"John Doe"},{"name2":"Marry Doe"},{"name3":"Michael"}];
const res = Object.assign({}, ...jsonx);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

> The `reduce()` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

```js
const jsonx =[{"name":"John Doe"},{"name2":"Marry Doe"},{"name3":"Michael"}];

var res = jsonx.reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, c), {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` for it:

```js
const jsonx =[{"name":"John Doe"},{"name2":"Marry Doe"},{"name3":"Michael"}]
    
    const res = jsonx.reduce((acc,curr) => ({...acc, ...curr}), {});
    
    console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap()` and `reduce()`

```js
const jsonx =[{"name":"John Doe"},{"name2":"Marry Doe"},{"name3":"Michael"}]

let res = jsonx.flatMap(x => Object.entries(x)).reduce((ac,[k,v]) => ({...ac,[k]:v}),{})
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
jsonx.reduce((r, a) => Object.assign(r, a))
```

OR

```
Object.assign({}, ...jsonx)
```